# Package Security Identifier (SID) and Client Secret required for parse.com web

Tags: windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I try to initialize Windows phone 8 application with Parse. I would like to use Push notifications. In the Parse's web settings are Package Security Identifier (SID) and Client Secret required. I am not able to find what should I insert into these two textboxes. Windows Phone application has only its own App ID...

Can you tell me what is the right way how to set the Windows phone application up?

Thank you.
Myth Rush

Comment: Did you ever try the answer given below? I'm in a similar situation but see you haven't responded so I'm not sure if that person's solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to register your application with the windows store

The following documentation goes through how to do it for azure.. But the process should be the same fore you.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push-preview/

In the Windows Dev Center page for your new app, click Services. 
[image]

In the Services page, click Live Services site under Microsoft Azure Mobile Services.

[image]

In the App Settings tab, make a note of the values of Client secret and Package security identifier (SID).

[image]

Comment: If an app I'm making is a WP8.1 app made using Cordova and I need the Client Secret for Parse. Can I use this method you descrived to get a client secret for that Cordova app then put it in Parse even if I have no intention of using Azure?

Comment: Yes this method should get you the client secret

Comment: I've managed to find the SID, but not client secret. For SID you need to go to dev.windows.com, log in, find or create your app and on its dashboard at App Identity you can find the SID. I can't seem to find the client secret, though... The site has changed since the screenshots above were posted, so maybe it's called differently. Could it be the "Seller ID", "Windows publisher ID" or "Windows phone publisher ID" on the same site under Account settings?

Comment: Got it, the pictures above are correct. You need to go to the dev.windows.com site, go to your app, or create a new one, go to the Services menu item and push notifications. There, under app settings, you will get all the needed info. The reply can be marked as a good answer. Thanks